# "Edit list" and "View network profile" links on Profile page are in different lines on Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, localization, russian-stackoverflow

English SO:

> [image]

Russian SO:

> [image]

From the UX perspective, it is not obvious that these are different links. And generally it doesn't look well with this alignment.

Comment: It’s not possible to place two long enough links on the same line inside limited width.